# Why does my pygame window freeze and crash?

Tags: python, pygame

Whenever I try to run my program it freezes up and crashes. I'm not a master pygame coder, but I'm almost sure its something to do with my main loop. It's supposed to allow the user to move left and right using arrow keys. I've tried adding a clock and changing the size of the screen but that didn't work. Here is the code:

```
import pygame
import sys
import random 
import time

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))

events = pygame.event.get()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

x = 50
y = 50

game_over = False
while not game_over:
    for event in events:
        if event.type != pygame.QUIT:

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x += 5
                elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x -= 5

        else:
            sys.exit()

    
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255), (x,y,50,50))
    clock.tick(30)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to include the error message generated by Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code needs to process the event queue *continuously*, otherwise your operating environment will consider your window to be non-responsive (locked up).  Your code is almost there, except it only fetches the new events once, but this needs to be done *every* iteration of the main loop.

```
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

x = 50
y = 50

game_over = False
while not game_over:
    events = pygame.event.get()                   # <<-- HERE handle every time
    for event in events:                     
        if event.type != pygame.QUIT:

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x += 5
                elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x -= 5
        else:
            sys.exit()
    
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255), (x,y,50,50))
    clock.tick(30)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! I usually don't put the events in their own list, but for this project, it makes it easier. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You cant do `foe event in events`, as when you call `pygame.events.get()`, you are updating them, you are updating them once and looping over them every frame, you need to use `for event in pygame.event.get():` so you are calling the function every frame and updating the events every frame

unless you were trying to do this?

```py
events = pygame.event.get
...
for event in events():
```

which does the same as above

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to get the events in a list, the main reason being so I can just type `for event in events:` instead of `for event in pygame.event.get():`, but the other way can be done too! I'll remember this next time!